# SSE Eventsource Asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, server-sent-events

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("/SSE/[action]")]
public class SSEController : Controller
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter> clients;
    static SSEController()
    {
        clients = new ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter>();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SSECallbackMsg()
    {
        await CallbackMsg("test");
    }
    private async Task CallbackMsg(string test)
    {
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = string.Format(test);
                await client.WriteAsync(data);
                await client.FlushAsync();
                client.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                StreamWriter ignore;
                clients.TryTake(out ignore);
            }
        }
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GETSubscibe()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent((a, b, c) =>
        { OnStreamAvailable(a, b, c); }, "text/event-stream");
        return response;
    }

    private void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent content,
        TransportContext context)
    {
        var client = new StreamWriter(stream,Encoding.UTF8);
        clients.Add(client);
    }
}
```

**Javascript Method of calling above is like**

```js
function listenForServerEvents() {
    var source = new EventSource('https://localhost:5002/SSE/GETSubscibe');
    source.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
        console.log('onopen');
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
        if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            source.close();
        }
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
    }, false);
}
```

when executing, above js function, i am getting error as **EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.**

Should add anything in startup.cs or is there any mistake., If anyone knows ,kindly help

Comment: Is there any special reason that we should return a `Task` from our action endpoint ? Everything I see is just we tried to return a string from our action endpoint, which can be easily replace with `Task<IActionResult>`.

Comment: There is no special reason for Task .. Problem is eventsource end point in JS is not hitting GETSubscibe function.